# codeigniter contact form

Tags: codeigniter, email

I want to know how to change this contact form receiving destination from database to an email instead. I was looking around the net to find a way how to do that, but couldn't. The whole purpose is to make a regular contact form so my clients can send emails to me "my site email". I know how to achieve this with php and no codeigniter, but with codeigniter things look different.

any idea how to do that?

**P.S** I can't post the code here because it is a little long, but here is the link to it: [enter link description here](http://gazpo.com/2011/07/codeigniter-jquery-form-validation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Codeigniter's Email Class in the process method in the Form controller.  Once the form has been validated (the else block) and after all the post data has been cached, do something like this (assuming you want to send the email via smtp):

```
$config = array (
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'your_email_server',
'smtp_user' => 'your_username',
'smtp_pass' => 'your_password');

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('your_email@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Your Subject');
$this->email->message("Your message string with any posted data included");

if (!$this->email->send())
{
//log an error
}
```

[Codeigniters Email Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Comment: Thanks @Spark. that is a good start, and I could make it work right away.

Answer (score 2):

In this case my ContactUs form will not work as I want to receive the information from visiters of my website.

```
$this->email->from('your_email@example.com', 'Your Name');
```

I should write the email, I am getting from the visiter

```
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');
```

I should write the email id of mine as I need that message on my id.

But did't know will it work or no luck.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand how CI works. CI is a MVC.

**Model View Controller**

Create a model which will handle all database interactions. So, when you send any data to your model which will contain the respective functions, you can send your data to the database.

Create a view which will be identical to the regular PHP page you can create. It will have your fields and other structure. On submitting the form, you need to send the data to the controller and from the controller, you should call the model. Inside the controller itself, you should use the `email` library which you can use to send the mail.

If you are not aware of how CI functions, please refer to the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Comment: Thanks. I know some about CI, but not sure how to deal with some stuff because I'm a newbie with CI just started a month ago.